# SuiteScript 2.0 Render PDF to Browser without Saving

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have a Suitelet rendering a PDF from various record types which do not currently have Advanced PDF functionality.

Everything works fine when I file.save() the finished PDF, but I would like the option to open the PDF in the browser without saving to the file cabinet first.

Currently, the action part of the script is this:

```
        var templateFile = config.getValue({fieldId:'custrecord_extpdf_template_xml'});

        var templateHTML = file.load({id: templateFile}).getContents();


        var renderer = render.create();

        renderer.templateContent = templateHTML;

        renderer.addRecord('record',rec);
        renderer.addRecord('config',config);


        if (SAVETORECORD) {
            var PDF = renderer.renderAsPdf();
            PDF.folder = config.getValue({fieldId: 'custrecord_extpdf_temp_folder'});
            PDF.name = param.rectype + param.id + '.pdf';
            var fid = PDF.save();
            var attachitem = record.attach({
                record: { type: 'file', id: fid },
                to: { type: param.rectype, id: param.id }
            })

            context.response.write(file.load({id:fid}).url )
        }
        else {
            var PDF = renderer.renderAsPdf();
            PDF.name = param.rectype + param.id + '.pdf';
            context.response.writeFile(PDF,false)
        }
```

When the variable SAVETORECORD is true, the PDF renders nicely, and opens in a new tab, attaches to the record, and is saved to the file cabinet.

However, when SAVETORECORD is false, a new window opens but is BLANK.

The Suitelet is called from a custom button trigger with the following code:

```
        var response = https.get({url: suiteletURL });
        if (response.body) window.open(response.body,'_blank');
        window.location.reload(true);
```

I've tried `context.response.writeFile(PDF,false)` and `context.response.writeFile(PDF,true)` but get the same result.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sleeping on it, I figured what I'd done wrong.

To save the PDF, the code stays as is.

To open in the browser without saving, I just needed to open the SuiteLet URL rather than the response.body from the button script:

```
            if (SAVERECORD) {
                var response = https.get({url: suiteletURL });
                if (response.body) window.open(response.body,'_blank');
            }
            else {
                window.open(suiteletURL,'_blank');
            }

            window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: I recommend calling the suitelet using `https.get.promise` in the client script so you don't block any UI events while the PDF is being generated.